# How to pass array from php sql to android list view?

Tags: php, android

i want to send String Array from my sql to android and display them in list view, im new to android and have no idea how

thanks in advance

heres my php code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db";
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore'); 


$date=date('Y-m-d');
$time=date('H:i:s');

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else{

    //$sql = "select * from sample order by time desc limit 1";
    $sql = "select * from sample";
    $res = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row =$res->fetch_assoc()){
        foreach($row as $key=>$val){
            echo $val."<br>";
        }
    }
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

i echoed just to show if my code is retrieving something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noel, you are on the right track.  What you want to do is to echo whatever values you want to pass to your android app.  You may well find that it is easiest to use the php command json_encode() to translate the data into json format and then to echo the string that results.

On the android side you will probably want to create a class that reflects the records coming from the website.  Something like:

```
public class myWebStuff {

  private static JSON_ID = "id";

  private static JSON_TITLE = "title";

  private int mId;

  private String mTitle;

  public myWebStuff() {

    mId = 0;

    mTitle = null;

  }

  public JSONObject toJSON throws JSONException {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject;

    json.put(JSON_ID, mId);

    json.put(JSON_TITLE, mTitle);

    ...etc.

    return json;

  }
```

You will also find it very convenient to write JSON formatted strings to local files on android devices, if you want to save the data you pulled from the website.

I hope that this helps.